# Ways for refreshing linked entity set collections within global static data context data objects

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Anyone whos been using LINQ to SQL for any length of time will know that using a global static data context can present problems with synchronisation between the database (especially if being used by many concurrent users). For the sake of simplicity, I like to work with objects directly in memory, manipulate there, then push a context.SubmitChanges() when updates and inserts to that object and its linked counterparts are complete. I am aware this is not recommended but it also has advantages. The problem here is that any attached linked objects are not refreshed with this, and it is also not possible to refresh the collection with context.Refresh(linqobject.linkedcollection) as this does not take into account newly added and removed objects.

My question is have i missed something obvious? It seems to be madness that there is no simple way to refresh these collections without creating specific logic.

I would also like to offer a workaround which I have discovered, but I am interested to know if there are drawbacks with this approach (I have not profiled the output and am concerned that it may be generating unintended insert and delete statements).

```
         foreach (OObject O in Program.BaseObject.OObjects.OrderBy(o => o.ID))
            {
                Program.DB.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, O);

                Program.DB.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, O.LinksTable);
                O.LinksTable.Assign(Program.DB.LinksTable.Where(q => q.OObject == O));}
```

It also seems to be possible to do things like `Program.DB.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, Program.DB.OObjects);`
however this appears to return the entire table which is often highly inefficient. Any ideas?